# Conditional Formatting Formula using MAX & AND

Tags: excel, max, conditional-formatting

I'm trying to highlight a cell within a range if it is the MAX number & it is greater than 0. I'm using this formula but it will not highlight if true. Formula returns "true" when used in a cell, but not in the conditional formatting.

Any idea's what I'm doing wrong or another way to achieve this goal? I'm working with percentages.

If the MAX percentage is 0%, I don't want to highlight anything. If the MAX percentage is greater than 0%, I want to highlight the MAX value.

`=I15=AND(MAX($I$15:$M$15)>0)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AND() expects the argument inside:

```
=AND(I15>0,I15=MAX($I$15:$M$15))
```

Comment: That fixed it. Thank you!